# How to get initial absolute orientation of device in Ionic

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic-framework, device-orientation

I would like to know if there is anyway to get the initial bearing of a user Position even if he is static and not moving in ionic native maps. Just like the flashlight pointer in google maps.

I tried W3c device orientation. it calibrates itself to the initial direction the user is facing as zero and not the bearing from the real north. This makes the user orientation wrong when displaying it on map.

I can use geolocation to get the bearing when the user starts moving but i would like to retrieve the direction when the user just started using the app so they can find out their direction even when not in motion